# Functional derivative of Ricci tensor respect to metric

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, curvature, variational-calculus, functional-derivatives

I am working on following functional derivative
$$
\dfrac{\delta R_{\mu\nu}}{\delta g_{\alpha\beta}}=C^{\alpha\beta}_{\mu\nu}
$$
Intuitively, it should be nonzero but I can not work it out.

Comment: How exactly do you interpret the Ricci tensor as a map between function spaces? And how exactly do you define said functional derivative? Is it supposed to be the Gateaux or the Frechet derivative evaluated at the metric or something else? The way the Ricci tensor is normally defined it does not make sense to "derive by the metric".

Comment: The result can be found in Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein-Hilbert_action) What's tripping you up in the calculation?